How to return a result from a fastapi endpoint processing an array of int32 numbers?
I have to do the following assignment:

Please create a public http or https service. It must have  a publicendpoint that accepts array of int32 numbers encoded as json in the request body and returns result as a number. Once deployed, pass the url of that endpoint to this service root in the request body as utf8 encoded string.
If successful you will get a success code to give to us via upwork chat.

I have made a service (currently still local) using FastAPI:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class ListRequest(BaseModel):
    numbers: list[int]

@app.post("/")
async def root(request: ListRequest):
    # int32 range
    int32_min = -2**31
    int32_max = 2**31 - 1

    for number in request.numbers:
        if not (int32_min <= number <= int32_max):
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="All elements must be int32 numbers")
    
    return {"result": "something???"}

I don't understand this part: return result as a number?
Can someone help me what exactly do I need to return?
Thank you.

I think you should clarify this with the person/entity that gave you the assignment because "return a number" is just unclear/ambiguous anyways, not matter the context.

I would guess by return result as a number you need to return all the numbers add with each other.... but I would ask the assigner because this is an unclear task

Sorry I have updated the whole message now. The thing that bugs me is that what should I return before passing that url endpoint to the service root?

You're going to have to ask the person who gave you the task. Nobody can tell you otherwise, or know what "service" refers to. There is no description of the expected result in the part you've included.

I Would still recommend asking more question when working on task such as this one.... it is an unclear task and if this is something that would go to production it might lead to multiple problems so don't be shy of asking questions about unclear things.... Also I've gone with the sum result because it's the most "human" go to thing  when asked for a "result".
I am assuming that you cant ask question this is why: I'm assuming what they want from you is to get the sum of the result from the request.number and after that you just need to pass the URL where the numbers will be add together or where the function will return an HTTPException:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

app = FastAPI()

class ListRequest(BaseModel):
     numbers: List[int]


@app.post("/")

async def root(request: ListRequest):
    # int32 range

    int32_min = -2**31

    int32_max = 2**31 - 1

    for number in request.numbers:
         if not (int32_min <= number <= int32_max):
             raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="All 
            elements must be int32 numbers")


    result = sum(request.numbers)

    return {"result": result}


Hello, this is a strong assumption considering the lack of details brought by the above post.

Hey @Lrx , yes it is but from experience of some coding challenges that I did on different websites when asked for the "result" most of time it is the sum of numbers   (which in my opinion is a dumb logic tasks needs to be clear)

@Shad0w I can't ask the question, that is why I am asking here. Will try out your solution. Do you know if I can pass the url of my endpoint (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000) to that root service or does it have to be public service (e.g. I host it on Heroku)?

your FastAPI service must be publicly accessible to be able to interact with the external service successfully...you could use heroku or another tool that makes your url public while working locally (free open source tool you can use): LocalTunnel this is a tool that creates a temporarily tunnel  this will also offer you random https link and reset when restarting the tunnel.

@bSmall I hope this helps.

@Shad0w Will try it out and let you know. Thanks.

@Shad0w I managed to host it on Heroku but I am having some issue. Here is the link to the question if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78948074/how-to-send-url-as-utf-8-encoded-string-in-httpie-post-request

hey @bSmall I saw your other question and I updated my answer can you try it ?

and can you try using curl for example: curl -X POST http://194.182.164.40/ \      -H "x-auth: ......." \      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \      -d '{"url": "https://fast-api-test-app-f922f0fd9a50.herokuapp.com/"}'
and I saw in your question you are using a diffrent url than "https://fast-api-test-app-f922f0fd9a50.herokuapp.com/" you were using "https://fast-api-test-app-f922f0fd9a50.herokuapp.com/process/" is that correct ?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think the task here is to create the interface of such endpoint (schema).
So, to complete this task you need to specify response model and return correct value.
Since it's not said how you should coerce array to one number, you can use sum or just return 42.
Pay attention, that it's said that you should return result as a number, not as JSON with number.
Also, you can make an improvement of your code by specifying list item's constraints in your model:
from typing import Annotated, TypeAlias
from annotated_types import Gt, Lt

MyInt: TypeAlias = Annotated[int, Gt(-2**31 - 1), Lt(2**31)]

class InputData(BaseModel):
    numbers: list[MyInt]


In this case it will be shown in openapi schema. And you don't need to check items in your endpoint (FastAPI will do it for you)

Do you know if I can pass the local url of my endpoint (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000) to that root service or does it have to be public service (e.g. I host it on Heroku)?

Have you got the answer to your initial question? Let's move step by step

Yes I did got the answer.

Next step is to close this question as resolved

Regarding your question about deploying - easier way is to use something like Heroku. You can also expose your local server to the internet, but it sometimes requires more work and not secure

Okey, I will open it using Heroku and open a new question if needed because I haven't done it before.

I managed to host it on Heroku but I am having some issue. Here is the link to the question if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78948074/how-to-send-url-as-utf-8-encoded-string-in-httpie-post-request
