How to send URL as utf-8 encoded string in httpie post request
I have to do the following task:

Please create a public http or https service. It must have a
publicendpoint that accepts array of int32 numbers encoded as json in
the request body and returns result as a number. Once deployed, pass
the url of that endpoint to this service root in the request body as
utf8 encoded string. If successful you will get a success code to give
to us via upwork chat.

The URL I need to pass is: https://fast-api-test-app-f922f0fd9a50.herokuapp.com/
to this URL: http://194.182.164.40/ with X-auth (which I have but won't post here).
I have tried the following using httpie:
http POST http://194.182.164.40/ x-auth:"....." url="https://fast-api-test-app-f922f0fd9a50.herokuapp.com/process"

but keep getting this error message:
parse "{\"url\": \"https://fast-api-test-app-f922f0fd9a50.herokuapp.com/process\"}": first path segment in URL cannot contain colon

How can I solve this?


Once deployed, pass the url of that endpoint to this service root in the request body as utf8 encoded string.

It says you're supposed to post only the URL itself. Not wrap it in JSON, and it doesn't say anything about calling the key "url" or anything like it. So I suppose https://... must be the only content of the request body.
In HTTPie, you can do that using the --raw argument:
% http -v --raw="https://fast-api-test-app-f922f0fd9a50.herokuapp.com/" 194.182.164.40
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 53
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 194.182.164.40
User-Agent: HTTPie/3.2.3

https://fast-api-test-app-f922f0fd9a50.herokuapp.com/


I did what you wrote but with X-auth: http -v  --raw="https://fast-api-test-app-f922f0fd9a50.herokuapp.com/" http://194.182.164.40/ x-auth:.... and got the 200 response and this response: https://www.imghippo.com/i/7F2KU1725445906.png

That sounds like this particular request successfully submitted the URL to that service, and that service called the URL with input, and your main app produced that as an error response. So, this question is answered; go back to your other question about how that fastapi should be implemented.
